# Oracle forms migration from 6i to 11g

Tags: forms, oracle, migration

I have migrated forms 6i to 11g and one of my forms function COMMIT got replaced with COMMIT_FORM, below is the log details for the same.

Can someone tell me what is difference between Commit and COMMIT_FORM ? 
also what is the different behavior it will make  ?

COMMIT changed to COMMIT_FORM

BR,
Shadab Hussain

Answer (score 0):

From the online help (for Forms 10G which is what I have):

> If you use a PL/SQL COMMIT statement in an anonymous block or a
>   form-level procedure, Oracle Forms interprets that statement as a call
>   to the COMMIT_FORM built-in.

So it would appear that there is no difference, but the upgrade process has made your code more "correct".

Comment: Thanks Tony for the information...   Also today I got one one more component which got replaced by upgrade process.  ROLLBACK changed to CLEAR_FORM

Comment: Probably the same applies - but check the online help (search for ROLLBACK) to be sure.